# JavaScript. Getting "resource"

Tags: javascript, referrer

When I browse, let's say, to `example.com/page/name?source=illia` I get to `example.com/password` page. This is an application set up.

In the dev tools, on the Network tab, I can see "resources" (not sure if I name it correctly) in the `Name` column.

So there are `/name?source=illia` and `/password` and all other items.

The question is how can I access `/name?source=illia` with js. Based on that I'd like to change the workflow.

`document.referrer` is an empty string

UPDATE:
[image]

Here is the screenshot from the devtools. Is it possible to get diagnostic?source=illia@example.com with javascript?

Comment: I don't think this is answer-able without either seeing the problem ourselves or significantly more information.

Comment: Provide screenshot(s)

Comment: Not sure if I understand completely, but do you mean `window.location` and its properties?

Comment: thanks. just updated the question

Comment: `window.location.href` is "https://example.com/password". It's current location. But I need the previous one

Comment: @IlliaKuzma Do you mean that you just want to know the url you got redirected from? Or do you need more information from that previous page?

Comment: @Ivar yes url is enough

Comment: @IlliaKuzma I'm not sure if that's possible. But a common way to redirect back to the initial page after logging in, is to add the url that is visited (and is redirected from) to the url. So you get something like `example.com/password?returnUrl=page%2Fname%3Fsource%3Dillia` and after logging in you get that url from the querystring to redirect.

Comment: Just to be clear. I don't need to go back. All I need it to READ that url. So basically I need to know that the initial page a user visited was `example.com/page/name?source=illia`. Does it make sense?

Answer (score -2):

Here you can call javascript to get whole url:

```
window.location.href
```

Then you can extract what you need.
One easy way is to split:

```
var url = window.location.href;
alert(url.split('?')[1]);
```

Hope to be useful;

Comment: `use jquery library, then things get so easy.` https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif